# Cannot use elements that were created with append method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an AJAX call that when it's done i have this code:

```
$(".results").append('<div class="horizontal result_element"><div class="result_photo"></div><div id="'+user_id+'" class="result_data">'+user_name+'</div></div>');
```

Later i want something to happen when i click on the class result_element:

```
$(".result_element").click(function(){
var url = "profile.php?user_id="+$(this).children("[class='result_data']").attr("id");
$(location).attr('href',url);
});
```

But it doesn't work and my thought is that jQuery create the html elements but doesn't appends them to the DOM.Any idea on how can i make this work with that method?

Comment: It's possible that `$(".results")` isn't matching anything. If so, `.append()` would do nothing and cause what you're seeing.

Comment: Woudl split the $(.results).append and creation of the elements $("div class...) and then hooking into the .click on $(".result_element", createdElements) work?

Comment: @Pluto append works perfectly.It creates the elements and displays them.But i can't use them later in jQuery.@Marvin can you explain better because i get cofused.

Comment: Just to clarify, the `$(".result_element").click` is being called *after* the `append`, correct?

Comment: @garrytowel. Here's a jsfiddle. It is working as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/2vt863pa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean with 'later' the time in the user-sight an not the time in the script.

The problem is that the jQuery doesn't know about the element if you create it after explaining that jQuery shell do x on event y. So if you set the `click`-event in `$(document).ready(function(){*here*})` and you create an element afterwards (after the document-ready was fired), jQuery doesn't know these fresh elements.

So to solve your problem, try to add the event after you created the element (creation not equal to appending!):

```
// created the element
var newElement = $('<div class="horizontal result_element"><div class="result_photo"></div><div id="'+ user_id +'" class="result_data">'+ user_name +'</div></div>');

// now set the event
newElement.click(function () {
    var url = "profile.php?user_id="+ $(this).children("[class='result_data']").attr("id");
    $(location).attr('href',url);
})

// now append it
newElement.appendTo($(".results"))
// or: $(".results").append(newElement)
```

And you can reorder the two last steps, so you first append it and then set the event, thats not the point. The point is, that you create the element first and then set the event.

Comment: Also works with my code if i add the click event on the parent element .results which exists before append.For the pros ;D

Answer (score 0):

I believe, click is not working on result_element class which is added dynamically. Try with following code snippet.

```
$(document).on("click",".result_element", function(){
   var url = "profile.php?user_id="+$(this).children("[class='result_data']").attr("id");
   $(location).attr('href',url);
});
```